# How to enable Advertising Features with Google Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We couldn't find any code on [Google Analytics Developers](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference) about how to enable Advertising Features for acccountId. Is it possible to make such request using API? If this isn't possible then `gapi.client.analytics.management.remarketingAudience.insert({` seems pretty useless because you still need to do it manually. Any solution?

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The API you mentioned is to create an audience segment.
You can't enable advertising features with API. You can enable it in Google Analytics interface or modifying code (in page or in GTM).

Comment: How to enable it in GTM?

Comment: Managing allowAdFeatures: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.simoahava.com/amp/analytics/allow-block-advertising-features-google-analytics/

Comment: Ok, then I wait until it will be available in the API. I believe more people will need it soon

Comment: Mark answer as solved if it has been useful to you and has removed your doubts, pls